# How can I access macOS API calls from C on Mac?

Tags: c, macos

I need to access macOS API calls from the C programming language rather than via Swift or Objective-C. A comparison to a Windows environment would be that on Windows, I can access calls like `CreateFile()`, `HeapAlloc()`, `WriteProcessMemory()`, `VirtualAlloc()` and etc... By simply `#include <windows.h>`

How can I do something similar on macOS Sierra or High Sierra? Note that I do not need to create a GUI application. I only need to access some low-level functions similar to the Windows API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the POSIX API because macOS is a POSIX-compliant system.

Answer (score 3):

macOS is, at its core, a UNIX-like operating system. Its low-level API calls are generally similar to those available on Linux or other UNIX-like operating systems -- for instance, you can interact with files using `open()`, `read()`, and `write()`, and you can allocate memory using `malloc()` and `free()`, or at a lower level using `mmap()` and `munmap()`.

A direct equivalent to Windows's `WriteProcessMemory()` is a little harder to get. Your best option here will be the Mach APIs like `vm_read()` and `vm_write()`. (macOS does not have the `/proc/<pid>/mem` interface found on Linux, and its version of the `ptrace()` interface is rather limited in functionality.) Keep in mind that some system processes may not be debuggable if [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you *can* call Objective-C APIs from straight C via the `objc_msgSend` family of functions, or by using the Objective-C APIs to resolve a method to an `IMP`, which you can then cast to a function type... but this is quite the pain.

The much, much better way to do this is just to mix some Objective-C code into the app. You can segregate it into a single source file, and just provide C function interfaces to your Objective-C code by doing something like:

MacSpecificStuff.h

```
void DoSomeMacSpecificThing();
```

MacSpecificStuff.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // or Cocoa/Cocoa.h, depending on what APIs you need
#import "MacSpecificStuff.h"

void DoSomeMacSpecificThing() {
    // Call a bunch of Obj-C APIs in here
}
```

Then just call `DoSomeMacSpecificThing();` from your C code and everything's hunky-dory, since your calling code won't care what language `DoSomeMacSpecificThing()` is actually implemented in internally.